# What is an alternitive for using action(); or forward(); in ZF for pulling out different controller/actions in the layout?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Basically in order to have a profile Block u need  - let's say profile controller, PhotoController, may be dashboard to show at the same page at the same time and to reach this in the zend framework is sometimes done through helper action() or forward, are ther better options?

Comment: Sorry, Ihadn't noticed that you already tried the action() helper so I deleted my answer.
As far as I know, there are no other options than forward() or the action() helper. But what's wrong with those?

Comment: Well The preDispatch() is gonna be called n(action()) times http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/ , The another option is to write View helper per widjet(lets say the photo part) - but here we are doing the Controller's work in the view helper - I don't know how bad is it but seems pretty bad =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question clearly. But you should avoid the action helper because it decreases significantly the performance of your application.

> "The Action View helper basically creates an additional
>   dispatch, copying the request object,
>   and creating a loop-within-a-loop .
>   The setting up of the dispatch process
>   is a costly one, anyone who has
>   profiled their code will have seen
>   just how much of the process of a Zend
>   Framework application this eats up.
>   Creating a whole extra dispatch must
>   be a bad idea, even the Zend Framework
>   Performance Guide notes this fact."

This quote is from [this article](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/) that explains why you should avoid it and what are the alternatives, why I believe to be the purpose of your question.

Comment: Hehe yes I read this post twice =). but all they propose is to use the action stack or use the view helper(in the comments). - I am confuced =(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe action helper or controller plugin using this method:

```
if ($condition) {
    $this->getRequest()
        ->setModuleName('mymodule')
        ->setContollerName('mycontroller')
        ->setActionName('myaction');
        // ->setDispatched(false); // redirect
}
```

Or controller plugin changing layout, using suitable view helpers.